# Mocking with FakeItEasy and DBContext does not work

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

Why is this test code not working?

Methode CheckDbAsync() in test-Class:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckDbAsync()
{
return await DbContext
                    .GetDatabase()
                    .CanConnectAsync(default);
}
```

Testcode with FakeItEasy:

```
var dbContext = A.Fake<IDbContext>();
           
A.CallTo(() => dbContext
                .GetDatabase()
                .CanConnectAsync(default))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));


var tc= new Testclass(dbContext);

bool result=await tc.CheckDbAsync();
```

Always returns false, not true.

Comment: As an aside, if you're using a modern FakeItEasy, you can replace `.Returns(Task.FromResult(true))` with `.Returns(true)`. I find it more readable, but your taste may differ…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What're `IDbContext` and `GetDatabase`? I can't find references to these things. Maybe because I'm not an EntityFramework user and maybe because they're your own things? It's helpful to have more context when answering these questions.

There's not a lot to go on here, but I'll guess:

`GetDatabase` is returning a different object every time you call it. This is the standard behaviour for unconfigured methods that FakeItEasy fakes.

So you configure one whatever-the-return-type-of-GetDatabase-is, and then another one is used within `CheckDbAsync`.

To verify, you can check the objects for reference equality.
To remedy, you probably want to configure `dbContext.GetDatabase` to always return the same whatever-the-return-type-of-GetDatabase-is.

(An alternative cause for the observed behaviour: there's no connection between `dbContext` in the test class and `DBContext` in the production code. We see you pass `dbContext` into the `Testclass` constructor, but we don't know what happens to `dbContext` after that. Or even if the `CheckDbAsync` method is part of the same `Testclass` class. I imagine it is, and that you just store the `dbContext` in the `DbContext` property, but I can't tell for sure, and thought I'd mention it, just in case that's the real problem.)